# How to convert a string literal into a string value

Tags: string-literals

hi i want to convert a string literal in to string value, can any one guide me in doing that

for eg   i want o convert the following string literal in to stringvalue.

"hello \r\n world"

in to "hello world"

Comment: isn't a literal, by definition, a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which language are you trying to accomplish this in?

For example, in C++ you could do:

```
   #include <string> 

...

   std::string s = "Hello \r\n World";
```

To create the object as an STL String (assuming by 'String Value' you mean you want to store the string in some form of class?

Your question could really benefit from a bit of clarification.